# Would you consider the "unit testability" of a system something to talk about before starting a new job?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mvvm, tdd

I walked into a new job and started working on a system that made me realize again, the importance of unit testing; and I mean proper unit testing that doesn't require an individual to click on buttons and interact with the test, or even hit the database or WCF or cross any other architectural boundaries inside its context. You should be able to run those tests anywhere anytime as many times as you like.

But this system is huge, it has about 700 projects spread across more than 300 solution files. This system directly references the dlls from a deployed location in 'Program Files' and 'circular references' are found in numerous places. After the developers change something in the code base, they would manually copy dlls to places or email them to each other. Some of the controllers are 21,000 (21K) lines of code. It can be a 'big ball of mud'.

I showed them how and where to add a seam or two to the system that wouldn't affect anyone so we could aim towards starting to unit test the system, because they seem to agree that they need this safety net and they noticed the whole industry is talking about its benefits. But now I am starting to get resistance from fellow architects on the team when 'a new property to expose something on a class' breaks their build.

This was the change. A new property exposing an existing private field.

```
public INavigationComponent CurrentNavigationComponent { get { return _currentNavigationComponent; } }
```

An architect and one of his developers don't have the patience (or know-how) to figure out where they have an old dll, so they ask me to remove the property, which I did, and he still couldn't build.

So if the team is not willing to add a single property to a class which would enable another level of testing, then I feel like I am preaching to a wall.

**Is a unit testable system too strict (or optimistic) a requirement for consideration of a new work environment?**

I'm guessing people would respond 'That it is my/your job to sell the concept and benefits of unit testing to your team, and if you can't do that, then...'.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based, there is no right and wrong. I will say that if you feel like you've tried but can't get people to see the benefits, and you don't like the way things are, then perhaps this workplace isn't for you. Sounds to me like a hellish build system they have there.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I disagree with your first sentence. There are right and wrong ways to develop software. Writing testable code is the right way to do it. I'd agree with your advice though: if others in the organisation aren't willing to listen to advice on how to improve things, the OP does just have the choice of leaving or lumping it.

Comment: @DavidArno There isn't an *absolute truth* to this. I know systems that don't use any unit-tests, but have great QA and work really well. It really varies on the characteristics of the development group and the product. This also shows the OP why this question doesn't fit on SO.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Yes the build system was quite a challenge, it has improved quite a bit over the last couple of months. People in our dev team are now copying dlls much less and using the improved build utility to decide when to deploy a dll. We also got the build down from 6.5 minutes to anything between 10s to 2 minutes depending on which project was changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to the real world.

In my experience comprehensive unit testing typically increases development time by a factor of ~5; the jury is still out on how much time it saves in the long term. If you work in an industry where quality control is paramount (aviation and medicine are two that immediately spring to mind) then it's a no-brainer, but for most industries there are many other factors at play including time-to-market issues, cash flow, marketing requirements, competition forces and a whole lot of other stuff that bears no relation to actual programming whatsoever.

It's important to keep things in perspective. As a new hire it's not your job to tell them how to develop their systems. The best you can do is demonstrate that you'll work with your team and the other departments for the good of the company, even if it means having to make compromises. Don't get me wrong, it's your responsibility to communicate to your superiors your concerns about the project, particularly when you think those concerns may have long-lasting ramifications. But then it's also your job to accept whatever decisions are made, even when they go against you, and do your job the best you can regardless.

Bottom line: being a good coder is only one small part of being a good programmer.

Comment: That is a good answer. And I agree, not all industries require it from the word "go". Ironically, this one does in my opinion. A senior architect on the team agrees with the change I suggested (just a property), but he also hinted at the fact that I need to work on my soft skills, and try to get whoever opposes the change in my corner and on my side. But geese, going back to the original question, it would be a nice way to "avoid" going into a system with so many brick walls.